# How to write a fish function that delegates to jq?

Tags: shell, jq, fish

I am trying to write a fish function called `jq_select_keys` that selects a subset of keys from a given JSON.

The jq incantation to do this piece of magic is:

```
jq -r "with_entries(select([.key] | inside([\"bar\",\"baz\",\"qux\"])))" file.json
```

Now I'm trying to define a handy function called jq_select_keys that will take the filename and the keys that I am interested in, and spit out the subset. Here is what I came up with:

```
function jq_select_keys --description 'Selects given keys from json input'
  set key_names (for key in $argv[2..-1]; echo "\\\"$key\\\""; end)
  set key_names_joined (string join "," $key_names)
  set jq_args "\"with_entries(select([.key] | inside([$key_names_joined])))\""
  echo "Command: jq -r $jq_args $argv[1]"
  jq -r $jq_args $argv[1]
end
```

When I run `jq_select_keys foo.json bar baz qux` on my fish shell, I get the following output:

```
Command: jq -r "with_entries(select([.key] | inside([\"bar\",\"baz\",\"qux\"])))" foo.json
with_entries(select([.key] | inside(["bar","baz","qux"])))
```

Now, the interesting bit is that I can copy paste the output of the echo statement, and it runs as expected. But the output I get is just the query string that I passed to jq.

I am new to shell programming, so I might have messed up my quotes. But other than that, I have no clue how to get this thing to work!

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling jq twice, rather than having one invocation do all the work? You can use `--arg` to pass a sequence as a string, and then parse that string into a list internally. (Not posting an answer as I don't do fish).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: This does not execute `jq` twice. The other `jq` is inside a quoted string literal, and the `| inside` is part of the argument to the one `jq` call.

Comment: Ahh. Such are the risks of trying to interpret a language one doesn't read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am new to shell programming, so I might have messed up my quotes.

That's basically it.

It appears you've added one layer of quotes too many.

In fish (and most other shells, including e.g. bash and zsh), quotes are only special to the shell when used literally.

That means when a variable contains `"some string"`, then `echo $variable` will print `"some string"` - which means that the `echo` command received the string *with the quotes* (note: bash would also apply word-splitting here, so it would actually receive `"some` and `string"`, even though you might assume it is quoted).

I would suggest you go through your function one by one and simply `echo` the variables. Then imagine you passed *that exact string* to `jq` - would it work?

E.g. the `$key_names` bit:

```
set key_names (for key in $argv[2..-1]; echo "\\\"$key\\\""; end)
```

The purpose of this is obviously to escape all the keys (which are the arguments from the second onwards) for use with `jq`. That means they need to be quoted *once*. They don't need to be quoted a second time because the shell does not care about non-literal quotes.

So any key should look like `"key"`.

But when we put

```
printf '%s\n' $key_names
```

(which will print each key on its own line)

after this, we see

```
\"bar\"
\"baz\"
\"qux\"
```

That's *two* layers of quoting! The quotes themselves, and the backslashes escaping them.

So let's remove one:

set key_names (for key in $argv[2..-1]; echo "\"$key\""; end)

This will result in `"bar"`, `"baz"` and `"qux"`.

(This can be simplified to  `set key_names \"$argv[2..-1]\"` by using fish's [cartesian product](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#cartesian-product))

Now for the next bit:

```
set jq_args "\"with_entries(select([.key] | inside([$key_names_joined])))\""
```

Your intention here is to run this as if you had

```
jq -r "with_entries(select([.key] | inside([\"bar\",\"baz\",\"qux\"])))" foo.json
```

On the commandline. But when you use variables, you don't need to quote the string inside them again - all the splitting and other expansions have already happened once the value is assigned, and does not happen again when the variable is substituted.

So simply remove the escaped quotes

```
set jq_args "with_entries(select([.key] | inside([$key_names_joined])))"
```

and your function should work.

The result is:

```
function jq_select_keys --description 'Selects given keys from json input'
    set key_names \"$argv[2..-1]\"
    set key_names_joined (string join "," $key_names)
    set jq_args "with_entries(select([.key] | inside([$key_names_joined])))"
    echo "Command: jq -r $jq_args $argv[1]"
    jq -r $jq_args $argv[1]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 2):

jq is a funny beast. I don't know why your script just outputs the $jq_args contents.

It has a --slurpfile option that reads a file of JSON strings into an array variable. This saves you from dynamically constructing both the JSON array and the jq script body

```
$ function jqs
        jq -r --slurpfile keys (printf '"%s"\n' $argv[2..-1] | psub) \
            'with_entries(select([.key] | inside($keys)))' $argv[1]
end    

$ cat file.json
{"foo":"a","bar":"b","baz":"c"}

$ jqs file.json foo baz
{
  "foo": "a",
  "baz": "c"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is an elegant solution. I have accepted @faho's answer for explaining the problems with the quotes.